# How to pass List as an argument to a function in threading.Timer

Tags: python

How to pass a list as an argument to function in `threading.Timer(...)` ?
Please see the following code. I would like to pass nb[] as an argument

```
nb=['192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3', '192.168.1.4']
ping_thread = threading.Timer(12.0, pingstarter, nb,)
ping_thread.start()
```

pingstarter is a funciton and taking argument as a **list**.

I am getting the following error. If it is required I can post all codes.

Thank you.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 522, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 726, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: pingstarter() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is simple: you need to pass the list argument `nb` to `threading.Timer()` as the single element of a sequence (I usually use a tuple, note the trailing comma **inside** the parentheses):

```
threading.Timer(12.0, pingstarter, (nb,))
```

...or, a list

```
threading.Timer(12.0, pingstarter, [nb])
```

Why? Well, `threading.Timer()` takes a sequence of arguments and a `dict` of keyword arguments. See the [documentation on argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) for more info.

Your list `nb` is being interpreted as the sequence of arguments, not as a single argument, so `pingstarter` eventually gets called with like:

```
pingstarter('192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3', '192.168.1.4')
```

...instead of:

```
pingstarter(['192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3', '192.168.1.4'])
```

Hence, you need to wrap it in another sequence.

Comment: Thanks detly. Now it is working. I have replaced [nb] with (nb,)

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your `pingstarter` in another function:

```
def wrapper:
    nb = ['', '', '']
    pingstarter(nb)

ping_thread = threading.Timer(12.0, wrapper)
```

Alternatively, redefine `pingstarter` so it is expecting the arguments in the way they're being passed.  Instead of something like:

```
def pingstarter(nb):
```

do something like:

```
def pingstarter(*nb):
```

What this does is takes all arguments to `pingstarter` and concatenates them into a tuple, which is the variable `nb`.  This takes care of the problem that Timer is making the call `pingstarter(*nb)` instead of `pingstarter(nb)`.

Finally, you could pass `threading.Timer` a list containing a single element, the list you want passed:

```
ping_thread = threading.Timer(12.0, pingstarter, [nb])
```

which requires no change to your other code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer

```
nb=['192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3', '192.168.1.4']
ping_thread = threading.Timer(12.0, pingstarter, (nb,))
ping_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects

clearly states that the function is called with args + kwargs.

```
class threading.Timer(interval, function, args=[], kwargs={})¶
```

> ```
> Create a timer that will run function with arguments args and
> ```
>
> keyword arguments kwargs, after
>   interval seconds have passed.

So you need to define your method as

```
def yourmethod(*args, **kw):

   ...
```

and pickup the related arguments from *args, **kwargs

Comment: No, he doesn't need to change his function def at all.